# Mobile Responsive section

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of an issue with a site I am creating. I need an alternative of float: left; for these icons. below I will upload two screenshots of the mobile screen and the computer screen.

[Computer Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoZlQ.png)

[Mobile Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4AdC.png)

This is my code:

```css
.featureIcon {
    width: 70px;
    float: left;
}

.featureRowSplit {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.featureText {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #146eff;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row featureRowSplit">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/FeatureIcons/1.png" class="featureIcon">
                        <h3 class="featureText">Cheap</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/FeatureIcons/2.png" class="featureIcon">
                        <h3 class="featureText">Friendly</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/FeatureIcons/3.png" class="featureIcon">
                        <h3 class="featureText">Clean Code</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/FeatureIcons/4.png" class="featureIcon">
                        <h3 class="featureText">Quick</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/FeatureIcons/5.png" class="featureIcon">
                        <h3 class="featureText">Helpful</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/FeatureIcons/6.png" class="featureIcon">
                        <h3 class="featureText">Reliable</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Best Regards,
Ben J

Comment: Have you tried setting small or extra-small Bootstrap columns for the icons to control how they appear on mobile?

Comment: Yes but the text does not align right

Comment: How so? You could use a media query to shrink the font for those breakpoints.

Comment: I could yes but there would be a lot of media query's as it re-positions every time the device get's smaller

Answer (score 0):

Do want them to align in one column? If so, you can set the whole thing in an unordered list and put the image and header in there. For the css, put list-style-type:none;for the unordered list, and put display:block;and float:left; for the actual li elements.

Comment: Completed this but I need a lot of media query's